# Spring TransactionTemplate causes double commit

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have such situation:

```
@Service
public class BeanA {

  @Transactional
  public void doSomething() {
    List<MyEntity> entities = repository.findAll();

    entities.stream.filter(MyEntity::methodUsingLazyLoading)
      .forEach(entity -> beanB.doSomethingMore(entity));
  }
}

@Service
public class BeanB {

  private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public BeanB(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
  }

  public void doSomethingMore(MyEntity entity) {
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(
        TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);

    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            entity.changeStatus();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

I execute doSomething method in BeanA. It looks pretty simple, but the problem is that regardless entity is being saved (and flushed) in doSomethingMore method (due to value change), Spring is trying to save it one more time after finishing execution of the doSomething method (another commit with flush). What I'm missing here?

Comment: I've not used TransactionTemplate much but my understanding is that execute called in BeanB.doSomethingMore will start a new transaction (due to requires_new propagation) and then commit. But this would not not have any affect on the initial transaction created by beanA.doSomething, which will commit also after it completes. Do you actually need the first transaction, perhaps for lazy load? Do you actually need the requires_new propagation? If you need those things then maybe you can use TransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly in your first transaction. Hard to say without knowing more context.

Comment: Currently setRollbackOnly is my walk-around. I need both transactions and the second is requires new due to Async method invocation which I skipped in the example. In fact I would expect that transaction manager will figure out that change made to the entity has already been persisted and in the moment when first method finishes the entity is clean.

Comment: The JPA provider may be a factor. Is it Hibernate?

Comment: Yes,  it's Hibernate

Comment: Wish I had deeper knowledge, but since no others are offering suggestions... I think what is going on here is that REQUIRES_NEW causes Spring to create a new hibernate session, attaching your entity to it. So doSomethingMore commit detaches the entity from the new session and does not detach the entity from the session in doSomething. You could try detaching them yourself in doSomething - using EntityManager.clear, or session evict on individual entities.

Comment: @splonk I think you're right. But I'm thinking that the second commit is not a problem - probably the root of this issue is that Hibernate is trying to save the same entity twice - additionally without updating version